# ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback has no effect in some devices(Android7)

Tags: java, android

I developed an app to monitor changes in network status, but this app has no effect when running on an Android 7 device. Here is some core code:
[image]
[image]

The following is the printed log:
09-19 17:54:42.237 D/ZnetworkCallback( 2888): 网络连接成功
09-19 17:55:43.661 D/ZnetworkCallback( 2888): 网络已断开连接

The normal log should be like this:
D/ZnetworkCallback( 2888): 网络连接成功
D/ZnetworkCallback( 2888): net status change! 网络连接改变:[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=15000Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=30000Kbps Specifier: <TelephonyNetworkSpecifier [mSubId = 2]> AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: -1 RequestorPackageName: null]
D/ZnetworkCallback( 2888): 当前在使用数据网络上网
D/ZnetworkCallback( 2888): 网络已断开连接

It can be clearly seen that the onCapabilitiesChanged() method does not

Why onCapabilitiesChanged() has no yn?

Answer (score 0):

```
class NetworkAvailability(var context: Context) {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        val currentnetwork = cm!!.activeNetwork
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm.run {
                cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                    result = when {
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                            return cm.getNetworkCapabilities(currentnetwork)!!
                                    .hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) && cm.getNetworkCapabilities(
                                    currentnetwork
                                )!!.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)


                        }
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            cm.run {
                cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        result = true
                    } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        result = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    /**
     * @isInternetAvailableM(context)
     * this code for minimum sdk version is M
     * */
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun isInternetAvailableM(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        val capability =
            connectivityManager!!.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        return capability?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) ?: false

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you share a Java language version of the code? I haven't mastered the Kotlin language yet. You can also explain the idea in detail. I will modify my code according to this idea.

Comment: I really want to know the reason why onCapabilitiesChanged() is not executed